# Excel Instance Restrict all other Workbooks to open. Open in new instance instead

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba form that I wanted to be alone in an Excel Instance.
I am trying to use this code I found in the net but it closes my tool

```
    Private Sub oAppEvents_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
 
    Dim oNewApp As New Application
 
    Wb.Close False
    oNewApp.Workbooks.Add
    oNewApp.Visible = True
 
End Sub
 
Private Sub oAppEvents_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
 
    If Wb Is Me Then Exit Sub
    Set oWb = Wb
    oWb.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
    Application.OnTime Now, Me.CodeName & ".CloseWB"
 
End Sub
 
Private Sub CloseWB()
 
    Dim oNewApp As New Application
 
    oNewApp.Workbooks.Open oWb.FullName
    oNewApp.Visible = True
    oWb.Close False
 
End Sub
```

What i want is that:

1. When there is an existing excel Instance - The tool will open in an separate new instance
2. When there is no excel instance - the tool isopen nomally in an Excel instance
3. When tool is open and I will open any other workbook - All other workbook should be open in a separate instance
4. This Excel instance of the Tool should contain only the tool and no other workbook.

I hope someone can help me resolve my dilemma. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by using this code. I put this code in the Workbook Module

```
Dim AppClass As New Class1


Private Sub Workbook_Open()


'Seperate Instance Declaration
Set AppClass.App = Application


'Maintain seperate instance for workbooks from this application
Call SeperateInstances


End Sub

'create seperate instances if other workbooks are already open
Private Sub SeperateInstances()


Dim oNewApp As New Application


If Application.Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
         
    If Application.Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
        Me.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
        oNewApp.Workbooks.Open Me.FullName
        Me.Close False
    End If


End If


End Sub
```

Then created anew class and put this code:

```
'Creating seperate instances using events
Public WithEvents App As Application
'Create a seperate instances for any excel files trying to open while this is open
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    
    Dim xlApp As Application
    
    If Wb Is ThisWorkbook Then Exit Sub
    Wb.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Workbooks.Open Wb.FullName
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Wb.Close False


 
End Sub


Private Sub App_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
    
    Dim xlApp As Application
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Wb.Close False
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have just the form in a new instance, the workbook containing the form needs to be in a new instance. Therefore you need to add code to the Open event of the Workbook, not the form. The code below checks to see if there are other workbooks in the same instance, and if so, re-opens the tool in a new instance and closes the one in the shared instance. Note the change to ReadOnly in the shared instance before attempting to re-open - this ensures the new instance can be edited

```
    Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Check that this is the only workbook in this instance
    If Application.Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
        'To ensure the other instance is NOT readonly after opening
        ThisWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly
        'Create a new instance of Excel
        With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            .Visible = True
            .EnableEvents = False
            'Re-open an editable copy of this workbook
            .Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.FullName
            .EnableEvents = True
        End With
        'Get this workbook out of this instance
        ThisWorkbook.Close False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. Yes the form also contains a workbook. 

But i dont want it to reopen everytime i open a different workbook. I want the instance of the form stay intact.

Comment: And yes, sorry. I just notice that the code i provided is incomplete. I have also that code you provided in my script.

Comment: No. If this is an Excel VBA Form (implied by the tags you used) then it does not contain a Workbook, the Workbook contains the form. As far as I am aware you cannot "move" a workbook from one instance of excel to another. The form will stay "intact" in it's own instance of Excel, it will not close when other workbooks are open.  To prevent other workbooks using the same instance you either have to have code in them all (not sensible), or force all workbooks into their own instance of Excel - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/force-excel-to-open-new-instance